# Qual é a finalidade do retorno da função main e a importância desta função?

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber qual é a importância da função `main` e qual é a finalidade do retorno dela que é um inteiro?

Veja um exemplo mínimo da implementação da função `main`:

```
int main()
{
    printf("StackOverFlow\n");
    return (0);
}
```

Em que este retorno implica na execução do meu programa?

Comment: Já ouvi falar que isso é um retorno para o sistema operacional. "0" significa que o programa executou com sucesso ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normalmente as linguagens precisam de um ponto de partida. Em `java`, `c`, `c++`, `ada`, `pascal`, `assembly`, etc, é usado um método ou um bloco (no caso do pascal) para saber onde a aplicação irá começar.

Em *Assembly* o código começa no método `_start` (se for Linux), o *C*, decide que o programa deve começar no `main` e o pascal tem um cloco de `begin` e `end.` para dizer onde a aplicação iniciará.

O retorno do método serve para saber se ocorreu tudo bem durante a execução do seu progama.

Exemplo de uso do retorno:

```
$ gcc main.c -o compiled
$ echo $?
```

Caso o arquivo seja compilado com sucesso irá retornar **0**, os outros valores são para diferentes tipos de erro.

Outro método de uso é:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared -O2 mylib.c -o libmy.so &&
$ gcc main.c -o compiled ./libmy.so &&
$ echo "compilado com sucesso!" ||
$ echo "Erro ao compilar!"
```

O simbolo `&&` refere-se a uma condição `e`, se os 2 arquivos foram compilados com sucesso, será chamado o primeiro `echo`, pois ele faz parte da condição `e`, caso contrario, será chamado o segundo `echo`, pois a condição `or` só é chamada caso o `e` seja falso.

Answer (score 6):

Na linguagem C o valor de retorno da função `main` é passado para o sistema operacional, e pode ser testado pelo processo pai.

Um exemplo concreto: no Windows, quando você trabalha numa "janela DOS", esse valor de retorno da função `main` é o valor que recebe a variável de ambiente ERRORLEVEL.

```
c:\tmp> prog_teste.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    echo prog_teste executou sem erro
) else (
    echo houve erro na execução de prog_teste
)
```

No Linux (e UNIX) o valor de retorno é deixado na variável do shell $?, que também pode ser testada logo a seguir à execução do programa

```
$ ./prog_teste
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo prog_teste executou sem erro
else
    echo houve error na execução de prog_teste
fi
```

Em C++ é permitido omitir o comando `return` da função `main`, e neste caso o valor retornado é 0.

Em C, a partir da versão C99 esta omissão também é permitida, e o comportamento é igual ao da liguagem C++.

No shell do Linux (e UNIX) é possível fazer o teste de "sucesso" de um programa sem fazer o teste explícito de comparação com 0, basta testar o nome do programa.

```
$ ./prog_teste
if ./prog_teste; then
    echo prog_teste executou sem erro
else
    echo houve error na execução de prog_teste
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

Os experientes que me corrijam, mas creio que seja main a classe principal do programa, onde o programa começará a rodar.

Já o return, como temos `int main()`, temos a indicação que essa classe devolverá um tipo inteiro, por isso return(0). Poderíamos simplesmente criar `void main()`, indicando que não haverá retorno nenhum, ou seja, vazio (void).

Espero que tenha te ajudado.

Comment: Não existe classes em C, e mesmo que fosse java, seria errado afirmar que "main é uma classe". As classes só armazenam dados e métodos, não tem como colocar uma sequencia de instruções em uma classe, apenas em métodos.

Comment: Boa! esqueci que estava lidando com C... rsrsrs
poderia dizer então que é um tipo de indicador? indicar que o bloxo x faz parte do programa principal e deve começar a ser rodado dali, eria errado?

Comment: não creio que indicador seja o termo correto, acho que dizer método apenas, é mais direto.

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado pela ajuda